# SELECT column/s based on boolean value

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I have a left join select statement that I want to select specific columns based on the value of a variable that has either a '0' or a '1'. I thought I could implement this using CASE, but I don't seem to be having any luck.

If `$variable` contains a '0' I want my select statement to retrieve only `users.user`, `table2.total1` and `table2.total2`, but if the `$variable` contains a '1' I want to select only `users.user` and `table2.total`.

```
$value = '1';
$conn->query(
  "select users.user, table2.total, table2.total1, table2.total2 
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total AND $table2.date = CURDATE() 
  WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales'
");
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this with sql, if in fact the query differ only by the select clause you could use a conditional and a variable:

```
$value = '1'; 

if($variable == '1') {
  $select = "select users.user, table2.total1, table2.total2 ";
}
else {
  $select = "select users.user, table2.total ";
}

$conn->query(
  $select . "
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total AND $table2.date = CURDATE() 
  WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales'
");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could do it with a simple if else but I thought it would be more efficient to do it all on one select statement. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about efficiency since this simple code runs fast enough that you don't have to worry about performance (it's one variable and a conditional), but I do think that this solution is more readable than over engineering a very simple query.

Comment: Only one query in this example is executed.. but the SQL you send to the database is different based on the conditional.